# How to approach sorting and pulling data by grouping from range of Cell Values?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to use MS Access for a database project.

I basically just want to pull information from a prompt like:

> Please Contingency Number:

And information would pop in front of me with all the specific information related to that entry.

Example below:

```
Contingency
CONTINGENCY 'XX:1_XX'
DISCONNECT BUS 1
DISCONNECT BUS 2
DISCONNECT BUS 3
DISCONNECT BUS 4
DISCONNECT BUS 5
DISCONNECT BUS 6
DISCONNECT BUS 7
END
```

So if I typed in the prompt: `Contingency 'XX:1-XX'`, all that information from above would show up in front of me. That is the goal. I am only using one column because this came from a `.txt` file. I don't think I need additional columns for identification purposes.

I tried using Access but I don't know how to filter out data to only show the row outputs rather than the column outputs.

I have no code, I am not proficient in SQL or any of that.

Results: Only `"CONTINGENCY 'XX:1_XX'"` would pop after running query.

Comment: What have you tried? Use Access query builder to help build query. This is very basic Access functionality. Edit question to show attempted SQL statement.

Comment: This is not for Access but for Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someday this will be helpful, for better or worse? :D

I suggest importing your text file into an access table called [Contingencies] with at least two text fields: 1) contingencyNumber 2) contingencyMessage then adding a click event to a button in form design that will build a string for a msgbox based on all the contingencyMessage fields for the contingencyNumber entered.

```
'define some variables
dim rstContingency as dao.recordset
dim txtInput, txtOutput, sql as string
txtInput = inputbox("Enter Contingency Number","Enter Contingency Number","NA")

'build a sql string
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Contingencies] WHERE contingencyNumber = '" & txtInput  & "'"

'assign recordset
set rstContingency = currentdb.openrecordset(sql, dbopensnapshot, dbreadonly, dbreadonly)

'loop through records until EOF (end of file)
'each time adding the message to the output string
while not rstContingency.eof
  txtOutput = txtOutput & vbcrlf
  rstContingency.movenext
wend 

'display original input and the accumulated messages for output
msgbox "Contingency: " & txtInput & vbcrlf & txtOutput
```